# Add -c flag to v.surf.idw call from PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-grass-plugin

This code is part of a plugin I created. MY QGIS version is 3.28, my GRASS GIS version is 7.

```py
rasterized = processing.run("grass7:v.surf.idw", {
    'input': points_vector_layer,
    'npoints': 12,
    'power': 2,
    'column': 'bin', '-n': True,
    'output': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
    'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT': "PROFILE=GeoTIFF,PREDICTOR=3,BIGTIFF=YES",
    'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER': None,
    'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER': 2},
    is_child_algorithm=True,
    context=context, feedback=feedback)['output']
```

When I run this code, it works, but the logs show an error:
ERROR 6: ...\output.tif, band 1: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.

After troubleshooting that for a bit, it seems the fix is setting the -c flag for the r.out.gdal call following after v.surf.idw.

But my question is, how do I do that from QGIS where the r.out.gdal call happens in the background - outside my immediate control? I'm not sure how to do it from the GUI either, nevermind from code.

Answer (score 0):

My only lead at the moment is

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Processing/QgsProcessingContext.html

I think that processing.run is an example of "`QgsProcessing`", and that it contains the ability to attach "`QgsProcessingContext`", and that perhaps could contain "`.Flags()`"

Could be a bit lost here though